# "Google" and "Facebook" login is not keyboard accessible

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, accessibility

At the login page `https://stackoverflow.com/users/login` there are two buttons that allow to log in using Google or Facebook. These two buttons are only accessible by mouse and cannot be selected using the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

While the page is still a little difficult to navigate due to other issues like [the search help needing to be manually dismissed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419744/6083675), it does seem to be keyboard accessible now.

Simply tab past the top bar, press escape (to get rid of the search help), and select what option you want.

Comment: Yep, looks like this issue was fixed at some point.

Comment: I can confirm that the issue is fixed.