# The search dropdown does not hide when it loses focus

Tags: bug, status-review, design, accessibility, search-box

To reproduce:

1. Open the Stack Overflow home page.
2. Tab into the search bar. A dropdown panel will open like it should.
3. Press tab thrice to move to the profile icon on the navbar. The panel should close after having lost focus, but it doesn't.

Since the dropdown does not close, even if the focus moves to one the elements under it (notably the Ask Question button), the focus on the elements cannot be seen well.

[image: repro]

Comment: A workaround would be to press the escape button to close the search menu.

Comment: No repro on Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, Firefox 103.0.2

Comment: Repro'd on Chrome (latest version) for Windows 11. // Side note: You should include the browser you're using, its version and your OS when reporting such bugs.

Comment: This is not a "tooltip". It's a complete pop-up, essentially a non-modal dialog. But, yes, it should go away when the search textbox (or controls it, itself, contains) is no longer focused.

Comment: @DavidPostill Windows 7?!? I think the "two versions previous" only applies to the browser, but maybe we should apply it to the OS too... ;-P

Comment: Also reported on MSE: [Close search "help" box on unfocus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383039/348196)